# batch file creates log file with incorrect log name

Tags: batch-file

Batch file creates log file with incorrect log name.

I am running on Windows 10

There are two batch files.

1. Bat File 1 sets up some these variables and calls the 2nd batch file.
   `V_FILE_DIR`, `V_BAT_FILE_DIR`, `V_FILE_NAME`, `V_FILE_DAYS_OLD`, `V_LOG_FILE_NAME`.
2. Bat File 2 accepts the environment variables sent by the Bat File 1. 
   and uses them to look for files in a directory that are greater than N days old.
   It creates a log file with the number of files it is going to delete and a list of the files that will be deleted.
   then it deletes the files.
3. These batch files work perfectly when I execute them from Windows Explorer. 
   When they are executed by Windows Scheduler they delete the files but the log file is given the incorrect log name and the deleted file are not listed inside the log file.

```
: ---- remove_MVIEW_SERVICE_BI_PART_MASTER_old_files.bat
: Bat file #1 
@set V_FILE_DIR="C:\Users\khughes\Desktop\KCH_WAKA-PDMDB-V01_WINDCHILL_PROD\Oracle\0BAT\MVIEW_SERVICE_BI_PART_MASTER"
@set V_BAT_FILE_DIR="C:\Users\khughes\Desktop\KCH_WAKA-PDMDB-V01_WINDCHILL_PROD\Oracle\0BAT\REMOVE_OLD_FILES"
@SET V_FILE_NAME="*.LOG"
@SET V_FILE_DAYS_OLD=14
@SET V_LOG_FILE_NAME=MVW_SRVCE_BI_PRT_MSTR

call %V_BAT_FILE_DIR%\remove_old_files.bat %V_FILE_DIR% %V_BAT_FILE_DIR% %V_FILE_NAME% %V_FILE_DAYS_OLD% %V_LOG_FILE_NAME%
```

```
: Bat file #2    
@IF [%1]==[] goto NOPARM

:---> Set variables section
@set V_FILE_DIR=%1%
@set V_BAT_FILE_DIR=%2%
@SET V_FILE_NAME=%3%
@SET V_FILE_DAYS_OLD=%4%
@SET V_LOG_FILE_NAME=%5%

@set V_HOUR=%time:~0,2%
@if "%V_HOUR:~0,1%" == " " set hour=0%V_HOUR:~1,1%
:echo hour=%V_HOUR%

@set V_MIN=%time:~3,2%
@if "%V_MIN:~0,1%" == " " set min=0%V_MIN:~1,1%
:echo min=%V_MIN%

@set V_SECS=%time:~6,2%
@if "%V_MIN:~0,1%" == " " set secs=0%V_MIN:~1,1%
:echo V_SECS=%V_MIN%

@set V_MONTH=%date:~-10,2%_%date:~-7,2%_%date:~-4,4%
@set V_YEAR=%date:~-4%

@set V_DATE_TIME=%V_MONTH%__%V_HOUR%_%V_MIN%_%V_SECS%

:---> Code section
@echo off
set "File=tmpfile"
set /a count=0

SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion

forfiles /p %V_FILE_DIR%  /m %V_FILE_NAME% -d -%V_FILE_DAYS_OLD% /c "cmd /c echo The extension of @file is 0x09@ext") >> tmpfile

for /F "tokens=* delims=" %%a in ('Type "%File%"') do (
         Set /a count+=1
     Set     "output[!count!]=%%a"                                                     )

IF %count% EQU 0 (Echo No files found to delete) ELSE (Echo %count% files were found to delete)

set V_NEWFILENAME=%V_BAT_FILE_DIR%\remove_%V_LOG_FILE_NAME%_%V_DATE_TIME%.log

echo "--->*******************************************" >> %V_NEWFILENAME%
echo "--->* %count% files deleted on %V_DATE_TIME%  *" >> %V_NEWFILENAME%
echo "--->*******************************************" >> %V_NEWFILENAME%
forfiles -p %V_FILE_DIR% -m %V_FILE_NAME% -d -%V_FILE_DAYS_OLD% -c "cmd /c echo del @path" >> %V_NEWFILENAME%
forfiles -p %V_FILE_DIR% -m %V_FILE_NAME% -d -%V_FILE_DAYS_OLD% -c "cmd /c del @path"
del %V_BAT_FILE_DIR%\tmpfile
goto exit1

:NOPARM
echo '******* Parameter Value Missing *******' >>  V_BAT_FILE_DIR%\remove_%V_LOG_FILE_NAME%_%V_DATE_TIME%.log

:exit1 
echo .  >> %V_BAT_FILE_DIR%\remove_%V_LOG_FILE_NAME%_%V_DATE_TIME%.log
echo '***********************' >> %V_BAT_FILE_DIR%\remove_%V_LOG_FILE_NAME%_%V_DATE_TIME%.log
echo '******* Exiting *******' >> %V_BAT_FILE_DIR%\remove_%V_LOG_FILE_NAME%_%V_DATE_TIME%.log
echo '***********************' >> %V_BAT_FILE_DIR%\remove_%V_LOG_FILE_NAME%_%V_DATE_TIME%.log
EXIT /b
```

Comment: What is the purpose of lines beginning with colon in batch file 1?

Comment: The first 'main' issue I can see is, is with the labelled section, mentioned in the first line of your #2 batch file. If no arguments were received, then, it is very unlikely that `%V_BAT_FILE_DIR%` and `%V_LOG_FILE_NAME%` were ever defined, and almost certainly `%V_DATE_TIME%` wasn't, as it isn't defined until later in that script. So even when you fix the typo `>>  V_BAT_FILE_DIR%` to `>>  %V_BAT_FILE_DIR%`, your log file would be saved to the root directory, `\ `, _(if the end user has write access to the root directory)_, and named `remove__.log`.